# uniform law on (0,1), integer part and independence

Tags: random-variables

Consider a uniform random variable $X$ on $(0,1)$ with density $p_X(x) = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$ and define 
$$
\{ 0, 1 \} \ni Y_X := \mbox{integer part of } 2 X \quad \mbox{and} \quad Z_X := X - Y_X.
$$
**distribution of $Y_X$**
$$
\mathbb{P} (Y_X = 0) = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} p_X(x) d x = \frac{1}{2} 
\quad
\mbox{and}
\quad
\mathbb{P} (Y_X = 1) = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 p_X(x) d x = \frac{1}{2}. 
$$
The law of $Y_X$ is a Bernoulli of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.

**distribution of $Z_X$**

Let $g(z)$ be a dummy fonction (continuous).
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} g(Z_X) & = \mathbb{E} g(Z_X) \mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_X = 0\} } +  \mathbb{E} g(Z_X) \mathbf{1}_{\{ Y_X = 1 \} } \\
& = \mathbb{E} g(X) \mathbf{1}_{\{ 0 \leq X < \frac{1}{2} \} } +  \mathbb{E} g(X-1) \mathbf{1}_{\{ \frac{1}{2} \leq X < 1 \} } \\ 
& = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} g(x) d x + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 g(x-1) d x\\
& = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} g(x) d x + \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^0 g(y) d y\\
& = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} g(x) d x
\end{align*}
The law of $Z_X$ is uniform on $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

**question about independence between $Y_X$ and $Z_X$ ?**
An authoritative professor told me that the two variables are independent, 
**BUT**
for all dummy function $h(z,y)$, I got :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} h(Z_X,Y_X) & = \mathbb{E} \left [ h(Z_X,0) | Y_X = 0 \right ] \mathbb{P} (Y_X = 0)  + \mathbb{E} \left [ h(Z_X,1) | Y_X = 1 \right ] \mathbb{P} (Y_X = 1) \\
& =  \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} h(z,0) d z + \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^0 h(z,1) d z. 
\end{align*}
So, if $h$ is of the form $h(z,y) = \phi(z) \psi(y)$
$$  
\mathbb{E} \phi(Z_X) \psi(Y_X) =  \left ( \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^0 \phi(z) d z \right ) \psi(0) + \left ( \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \phi(z) d z \right )  \psi(1)
$$
which is not
$$  
\mathbb{E} \phi(Z_X)  \mathbb{E} \psi(Y_X) = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \phi(z) d z \left ( \frac{1}{2} \psi(0) + \frac{1}{2} \psi(1) \right ) .
$$
Am I wrong to claim, standing up firmly on my feet, that the $Z_X$ and $Y_X$ are not independent?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the variables $Z_X$ and $Y_X$ are not independent. By construction, $Z_X$ is positive if and only if $Y_X=0$. Therefore
$$P(\text{$Z_X>0$ and $Y_X=0$}) = P(Z_X>0) = P(Y_X=0).$$
But $P(Y_X=0)=1/2$, which means that
$$P(\text{$Z_X>0$ and $Y_X=0$}) \ne P(Z_X>0) P(Y_X=0),$$
and therefore $Z_X$ and $Y_X$ are not independent.